# Quantitative data on number of insects per area over time?

Tags: data-request, historical, population, environment, biology

In my surroundings a couple of people / friends have the feeling that the number of insects has declined over a number of years.

Do you know of any sources of data which give quantitative numbers on **insects per area over time** for any country in Western Europe, Americas, Australia, where *insect* can be:

- fly
- wasps
- bees (wild type)
- mosquito
- or any similar indicator species?

A time range over more than 20 year would be appreciated. If the data set also included confounding factors, this would be a plus.

It seems that biodiversity measures a slightly different number, and for example I wasn't able to find interesting data sets on the European Environmental Agency's [website](https://www.eea.europa.eu/themes/biodiversity) for biodiversity (besides decline in common birds in Europe).

Any hints or tips where to look or what to search for?

Comment: not just you http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/05/where-have-all-insects-gone

Comment: Also, [this article](https://e360.yale.edu/features/insect_numbers_declining_why_it_matters) contains links to research papers. Perhaps some of them contain links to data or data itself...

Comment: Another recent article: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0185809